# Why the Note 3 in [class.temporary]/2? Shouldn't paragraphs (2.1) thru (2.6) have normative status?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[class.temporary]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#2)

The materialization of a temporary object is generally delayed as long as possible in order to avoid creating unnecessary temporary objects.

[**Note 3**: Temporary objects are materialized:

(2.1)  when binding a reference to a prvalue ([dcl.init.ref], [expr.type.conv], [expr.dynamic.cast], [expr.static.cast], [expr.const.cast], [expr.cast]),

(2.2) when performing member access on a class prvalue ([expr.ref], [expr.mptr.oper]),

(2.3) when performing an array-to-pointer conversion or subscripting on an array prvalue ([conv.array], [expr.sub]),

(2.4)
when initializing an object of type `std​::​initializer_­list<T>` from a *braced-init-list* ([dcl.init.list]),

(2.5)
for certain unevaluated operands ([expr.typeid], [expr.sizeof]), and

(2.6)
when a prvalue that has type other than *cv* `void` appears as a discarded-value expression ([expr.prop]).
**— end note**]

Comment: Because it's a paraphrase?

Comment: I don't think so. AFAICT this is the only place in the spec where those paragraphs are exposed.

Comment: Each bullet point here links to the normative parts that define what happens in each situation. Much like with code, they work really hard to avoiding duplication. Partly just because they're programmers, so they always do, but also for the same reasons we avoid it in code (such as avoiding conflict when later edits take place).

Comment: @Belloc That's why it's normative.  The actual text is behind those links, like [this section](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3)

Comment: I'd say the whole paragraph 2 should be a Note. «is generally delayed as long as possible» is not a normative wording but summary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The referenced sections ([dcl.init.ref] etc.) have normative wording that specifies exactly when temporary materialization occurs. This note exists only as a quick reference so you don't have to look through the whole standard to find all the situations where temporary materialization happens. If it were normative, then it would be redundant at best, and conflicting at worst. Making it non-normative preserves its usefulness while avoiding any potential issues.